# How to receive user input for Dictionary function in Python?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, input

I am trying to create a Dictionary of countries and their capital, but only from user input. The **key** will be the country name and the **value** will be the capital, so it would look something like this:

`capital_dict = {"France":"Paris", "Germany":"Berlin", "Japan:"Tokyo"}`

How do I make it so the user inputs the required information and the interpreter creates a dictionary from it?

Your help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `for` loop with `input`:

```
capital_dict = {}
while True:
    country = input('Enter country name: ')
    capital = input('Enter capital name: ')
    if not (country and capital):
        break
    capital_dict[country] = capital  # or capital_dict.update({country: capital})
```

If for any combination the user enters an empty string for `country` and `capital`, the loop will break.